# case_when conditions summing on different rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to define different crop sequences (CS) at different sites(SiteID) depending on the number of Years certain Crops are cultivated.

```
Crop = data.frame(SiteID=c('A','A','A','B','C','C','D','D'),
                Crop = c('soya','corn','wheat','corn','corn','soya','soya','wheat'),
                Years = c(2,2,1,5,3,2,2,3))
```

So far, I used case_when for single Crops and Years conditions but I would like to cumulate Years for different Crops like these 2 last conditions.

```
Crop  %>%
#  group_by(SiteID)
  mutate(CS = case_when(
             Crop =="corn" &  Years == 5    ~ "CoMo",
             Crop =="wheat" &  Years >= 3     ~ "Whea",
             (Crop =="corn" | Crop =="soya") &  sum(Years) == 5    ~ "CoSo",
#             Years[Crop =="corn"] + Years[Crop =="soya"]  == 5    ~ "CoSo",

       ))
```

Intermediate result would look like this:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  SiteID Crop  Years CS   
  <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
1 A      soya      2 NA   
2 A      corn      2 NA   
3 A      wheat     1 NA   
4 B      corn      5 CoMo 
5 C      corn      3 CoSo   
6 C      soya      2 Coso   
7 D      soya      2 Whea   
8 D      wheat     3 Whea
```

And in the end CS would be summarize by SiteID:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  SiteID SC   
  <chr>  <chr>
1 A      NA   
2 B      CoMo 
3 C      CoSo 
4 D      Whea
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show your expected output and explain the logic to reach there?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a try with explaination

```r
library(dplyr)

Crop = data.frame(SiteID=c('A','A','A','B','C','C','D','D'),
  Crop = c('soya','corn','wheat','corn','corn','soya','soya','wheat'),
  Years = c(2,2,1,5,3,2,2,3))

Site_crop <- Crop  %>%
  group_by(SiteID) %>%
  # Note that case_when will priority order match so the first match will be
  # the value. Therefore you also want to check if your condition is exclusive
  # or if they somehow overlap then you would need to priority which one first
  mutate(CS = case_when(
    # using any here to cover all record of a SiteID
    any(Crop =="corn" &  Years == 5)    ~ "CoMo",
    any(Crop =="wheat" &  Years >= 3)     ~ "Whea",
    # For this one I use length intersect to ensure that
    # Crop have both "corn" & "soya"
    length(intersect(unique(Crop), c("corn", "soya"))) == 2 &
      sum(Years[Crop %in% c("corn", "soya")]) == 5 ~ "CoSo",
    # Then finally if no match of any condition is NA
    TRUE ~ NA_character_
  ))
```

**Here is the data after `case_when`**

```r
Site_crop
#> # A tibble: 8 x 4
#> # Groups:   SiteID [4]
#>   SiteID Crop  Years CS   
#>   <chr>  <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#> 1 A      soya      2 <NA> 
#> 2 A      corn      2 <NA> 
#> 3 A      wheat     1 <NA> 
#> 4 B      corn      5 CoMo 
#> 5 C      corn      3 CoSo 
#> 6 C      soya      2 CoSo 
#> 7 D      soya      2 Whea 
#> 8 D      wheat     3 Whea
```

**Final otuput with `CS` for each `SiteID`**

```
Site_crop %>%
  group_by(SiteID) %>%
  summarize(CS = first(CS))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   SiteID CS   
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 A      <NA> 
#> 2 B      CoMo 
#> 3 C      CoSo 
#> 4 D      Whea
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: if I want to name a another crop sequence where "corn" and "soya" are present with any other crop. Should I specify length(intersect(unique(Crop), c("corn", "soya"))) == 2 or just just use sum(Years[Crop %in% c("corn", "soya")]) > 3 ~ "CSMix" ?

Comment: `length(intersect(unique(Crop), c("corn", "soya"))) == 2` the number `2` here is because there only two crop `"corn", "soya"` if you have 3 crop condition then number will be `3` and depend on the logics it may require you adjust the `c("corn", "soya")` in the calculate of year sum to include the additional crop as well.